# Highcharts.js : pattern in plot bands that resizes on zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I have a highcharts.js chart on my webpage representing hourly status of a device. I would like to add tick marks to each status axis representing divisions of an hour (half and quarter). 
For the moment I managed to add the data and create the chart style I need and added the highcharts pattern fill plugin with a png pattern (just testing, pattern is there only for an idea of what I would like to obtain and will be fitted right to the intervals).

For the moment I add the plotbands for each hour like this:

```
var width = $('.highcharts-plot-background').width()/24;
var height = $('.highcharts-plot-background').height();

for (i=0;i<24;i++) {
  chart.xAxis[0].addPlotBand({
      from: i, // Start of the plot band
      to: i+1, // End of the plot band
      color: { 
        pattern:'https://s28.postimg.org/8ujsr438d/pattern.png',
        width: width,
        height: height
      }
    });
}
```

[Full JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdomnita/b77d6n9a/)

The problem I have is due to the fact that I add the pattern to each plot band (hour) and calculate its dimension according to the initial size of the chart. This works ok when I show the chart but if I want to add zooming functionality the pattern backgrounds don't resize. Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify, the chart zoom function is not a literal zoom, which you may have been expecting - it's an adjustment of the axes to reflect the desired range of data. You'll have to build a function that uses the resulting axis scaling, and adjusts the scaling of your image accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I updated my fiddle with a function that should fill the full intervals with the right resized image but I still have trouble getting the exact min and max values from the axis and it does not work as expected all the time. http://jsfiddle.net/mdomnita/my6oyfqx/

Comment: It looks like you mistyped floor with ceil functions - http://jsfiddle.net/my6oyfqx/3/

Comment: I finally did it with highcharts css styling for gridlines and it looks fine. Updated the fiddle. There are some inconsistencies between browsers due to the stroke-dasharray lenghts from the gridlines having non-integer values. This can be seen when exporting png from different browsers. Other than that, I think I will stick with this solution for the moment as the plotband backgrounds do not scale well.